# Algebraic Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

prove $(a + x)^{1/2} + (a - x)^{1/2} \gt a$ for any real $a\gt 0$.

Comment: @Shawn: For all $x$? Surely not, put $x=a$.  The assertion becomes $\sqrt{2a} >a$, which is false if $a \ge 2$. Can you reformulate the question?  Maybe you are trying to find what values of $x$ satisfy the inequality?

Comment: Oops sorry the question is to solve for such for x to make this true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously $-a\lt x\lt a$ (Comment of Shawn).

Squaring both sides...
$(a+x)+(a-x)+2\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} = 2a + 2\sqrt{a^2-x^2} > a^2$

or
$2\sqrt{a^2-x^2} > a(a-2)$

(When $a\geq2$)

$4(a^2-x^2) > a^2 (a^2 - 4a + 4)$

or
$a^4 - 4a^3 + 4x^2 < 0$

or
$x^2 < a^3 - a^4/4$

or
$-a \sqrt{a - a^2/4} < x < a \sqrt{a - a^2/4}$.

(When $a\leq2$) (Comment of Arturo Magidin)

Since $a(a-2)\lt0$, $-a\lt x \lt a$ is enough.

Comment: Ah thanks for the solution, I guess I forgot you could simplify roots by multiplying their inner values.

Comment: Let $a=135/128$ then your equation gives $x>-\frac{405 \sqrt{5655}}{32768}\approx -0.9294$ but $x=-1$ works...

Comment: The third step assumes that $a-2\gt 0$ when it passes from $2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\gt a(a-2)$ to $4(a^2-x^2)\gt a^2)(a-2)^2$.

Comment: @user3123, @Arturo : oops..

Answer (score 4):

Squaring both sides, we obtain the equivalent inequality
$$2\sqrt{a^2-x^2} >a^2-2a$$
If $a^2-2a<0$, that is, if $0<a<2$, the inequality automatically holds for all $x$ at which the left-hand side is defined, that is, for all $x$ such that $|x| \le a$.

So now consider the case $a\ge 2$.  Then the inequality $2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}>a^2-2a$ is equivalent to $4(a^2-x^2)>(a^2-2a)^2$.  This simplifies to
$$4x^2 <4a^3-a^4$$
or equivalently $|x|<(a/2)\sqrt{4a-a^2}$.  Note that in particular there are no solutions if $a \ge 4$.

Comment: This one is the correct answer.